# Determine the radius of convergence of the series $\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty (10^{−n} + 10^n)x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Determine the radius of convergence, R, of the power series $\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ where $a_n = 10^{−n} + 10^n$.
I know the series diverges and the radius of convergence is 0 but how do I prove it?

Comment: How do you know that the series diverges?  How do you know that the radius of convergence is $0$?  Have you tried $x=\frac{1}{100}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the ratio test:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_nx^n}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{(10^{-n-1}+10^{n+1})x^{n+1}}{(10^n+10^{-n})x^n}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{(10^{-n-1}+10^{n+1})x}{(10^n+10^{-n})}\right|
$$

For what values of $x$ is this limit less than $1$?  To make this easier, we can divide the numerator and denominator by $10^n$ to get that this limit is the same as:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(10^{-2n-1}+10)|x|}{(1+10^{-2n})}.
$$

As $n$ increases, the limit approaches $10|x|$, so we can find appropriate $x$'s.

Answer (score 2):

The series does not have the radius of convergence $0,$ but rather $1/10.$